# How to stop/Disable Nagios email notifications

Tags: nagios

How Can I stop the email notifications. I am setting up a new server and getting tons of notifications. Wants to disable them for time being.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Click on "Process Info" in the left nav pane, and then "Disable Notifications", then "Commit".

Answer (score 24):

in nagios.cfg, set enable_notifications=0 and restart nagios

Comment: was looking for a way to disable all notifications temporarily while troubleshooting a new config, this did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can also do it at a contact level, by disabling notifications for your Nagios contact. 
E.g.:

```
define contact { 
    contact_name JohnDoe
    email johndoe@example.com
    host_notifications_enabled 0
    service_notifications_enabled 0
}
```

The other way to skin this cat is to use the *host_notification_options* and *service_notification_options* in the contact definition. Set them to `n` (none).

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this via NAGIOS's `command_file` named pipe, if you have that defined.  The advantages of doing it this way are it's internal to NAGIOS, it can be programmed from `at` or `cron` rather than requiring interaction with a web browser, and it doesn't require changing any of the config files.

To disable notifications (on CentOS6 EPEL NAGIOS - other distributions may have the command_file configured elsewhere):

```
echo "[`date +%s`] DISABLE_NOTIFICATIONS" > /var/nagios/rw/nagios.cmd
```

and to re-enable it later:

```
echo "[`date +%s`] ENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS" > /var/nagios/rw/nagios.cmd
```

Answer (score 1):

Set both:

- service_notification_period &
- host_notification_period

to **never** instead of **24x7**

Answer (score 0):

You can also stop your mail server (`service postfix stop`) on the Nagios server, if you are relaying through the mail server on localhost where Nagios is installed.  Then you can do `postsuper -d ALL` to delete all mails sitting in `mailq`.

Comment: You weren't to know this as a low-rep user, but that suggestion's already been made, downvoted, and deleted by its poster.  To quote one of the mods on the other (identical) answer, "*Sorry, that's a horrible solution. From the perspective of your Nagios logs and host/service availability data, they're going to show that you had an outage and that notifications were sent out. That makes the data useless for historical troubleshooting/trending. While this may be an acceptable solution for you, it's not something you ought to be suggesting is the "right" answer for a professional environment.*".