# Nagios notifications coming from NRPE client machine (NOT the Nagios server)

Tags: nagios, nrpe, notification

I have Nagios running on a Debian Jessie master server, with `NRPE` running on a Debian client. The root@localhost is getting a slew of emails - apparently **originating from Nagios (NRPE) on the client**, versus being sent by the Nagios master server.

As a troubleshooting step, I disabled all notifications on the Nagios master server - by disabling it via both the web interface and the nagios.cfg (via [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/549603/how-to-stop-disable-nagios-email-notifications)).

But the notifications keep going to the user.

**How can I disable this?** I don't see anything about notifications in the `nrpe.cfg`.

[image: Screenshot, forwarded email]

Answer (score 1):

NRPE does not have a way to send notifications of any kind.

This means you installed Nagios on the "client" machine.